# Retry policy is not working when opening connection asynchronously?

Tags: c#, async-await, enterprise-library

In my application I am using Enterprise Library Topaz(Transient Fault Handling Application Block). I am trying to implement SqlConnection.OpenWithRetryAsync. But its not working. I mean when I put my breakpoint it only hits first time and throws an exception. Here is what I have tried so fast,

```
    public static Task OpenWithRetryAsync(this SqlConnection connection, RetryPolicy retryPolicy)
    {
        return retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() =>
        {
            return connection.OpenAsync();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just dig into source and found that I get an SQL Error which is not transient. My error code was 10065 and error was,

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host.)

When I ran,

```
    public static Task OpenWithRetryAsync(this SqlConnection connection, RetryPolicy retryPolicy)
    {
        return retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
                throw CreateSqlException(10060);// got it form http://blog.gauffin.org/2014/08/how-to-create-a-sqlexception/
            }
        });
    }
```

Then my retry policy is working like a charm.

```
    public bool IsTransient(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex != null)
        {
            SqlException sqlException;
            if ((sqlException = ex as SqlException) != null)
            {
                // Enumerate through all errors found in the exception.
                foreach (SqlError err in sqlException.Errors)
                {
                    switch (err.Number)
                    {
                            // SQL Error Code: 40501
                            // The service is currently busy. Retry the request after 10 seconds. Code: (reason code to be decoded).
                        case ThrottlingCondition.ThrottlingErrorNumber:
                            // Decode the reason code from the error message to determine the grounds for throttling.
                            var condition = ThrottlingCondition.FromError(err);

                            // Attach the decoded values as additional attributes to the original SQL exception.
                            sqlException.Data[condition.ThrottlingMode.GetType().Name] =
                                condition.ThrottlingMode.ToString();
                            sqlException.Data[condition.GetType().Name] = condition;

                            return true;
                        case 0:
                            if ((err.Class == 20 || err.Class == 11) && err.State == 0 && err.Server != null && ex.InnerException == null)
                            {
                                if (string.Equals(err.Message, Resources.SQL_SevereError, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                                {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                            // SQL Error Code: 4060
                            // Cannot open database "%.*ls" requested by the login. The login failed.
                        case 4060 :
                            // SQL Error Code: 10928
                            // Resource ID: %d. The %s limit for the database is %d and has been reached.
                        case 10928:
                            // SQL Error Code: 10929
                            // Resource ID: %d. The %s minimum guarantee is %d, maximum limit is %d and the current usage for the database is %d. 
                            // However, the server is currently too busy to support requests greater than %d for this database.
                        case 10929:
                            // SQL Error Code: 10053
                            // A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server.
                            // An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
                        case 10053:
                            // SQL Error Code: 10054
                            // A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. 
                            // (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
                        case 10054:
                            // SQL Error Code: 10060
                            // A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
                            // The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server 
                            // is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed 
                            // because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed 
                            // because connected host has failed to respond.)"}
                        case 10060:
                            // SQL Error Code: 40197
                            // The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again.
                        case 40197:
                            // SQL Error Code: 40540
                            // The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again.
                        case 40540:
                            // SQL Error Code: 40613
                            // Database XXXX on server YYYY is not currently available. Please retry the connection later. If the problem persists, contact customer 
                            // support, and provide them the session tracing ID of ZZZZZ.
                        case 40613:
                            // SQL Error Code: 40143
                            // The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again.
                        case 40143:
                            // SQL Error Code: 233
                            // The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error during connection initialization process before login. 
                            // Possible causes include the following: the client tried to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server; the server was too busy 
                            // to accept new connections; or there was a resource limitation (insufficient memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server. 
                            // (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
                        case 233:
                            // SQL Error Code: 64
                            // A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. 
                            // (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) 
                        case 64:
                            // DBNETLIB Error Code: 20
                            // The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to does not support encryption.
                        case (int)ProcessNetLibErrorCode.EncryptionNotSupported:
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (ex is TimeoutException)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                EntityException entityException;
                if ((entityException = ex as EntityException) != null)
                {
                    return this.IsTransient(entityException.InnerException);
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The ADO.NET SqlConnection class comes with an OpenWithRetry method

For example:

```
connection.OpenWithRetry(retryPolicy);
```

Have a look at this website, I found it very useful when I was looking at getting a retry policy in place

http://geekswithblogs.net/ScottKlein/archive/2012/01/27/understanding-sql-azure-throttling-and-implementing-retry-logic.aspx

Comment: The ADO.NET SqlConnection class DOES NOT COME with an OpenWithRetry method.